# How to plot color plot or density plot for complex numbers?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, root

I have a `res` function that takes as input complex value of a certain `omega` variable and returns the absolute value of the residue (also complex) of a continued fraction.

I'd like to test the `res` function for various omega values and see which of those values yields a residual value closest to zero. So I would see which omega corresponds, which would be, in a sense, the root of the equation for the residue of the continued function. Therefore, I generated a list of omegas as follows:

```
N = 400

omega = [complex(np.random.uniform(0.001, 15), np.random.uniform(0, 2)) for i in range(N)]
```

And I imposed each `omega[i]` value on the `res` function. Truncating the lists, for the omega list

```
omega = [(8.89186304186803+1.8580361935398448j), (4.250554058118386+0.34692636983137204j),(13.77975011058525+0.4067498913305867j), (11.848491447761512+1.1353493824887473j), (5.368197310760776+1.603262808639006j), (7.953834937525846+0.31087387982821735j),
 (12.589975089023985+1.9010925629632527j),(0.8533967396680111+0.9083830823882479j),
 (11.966071152073017+1.7535358294965886j), (6.723597895069045+0.5943732982185757j)]
```

I got the following the absolute value of the corresponding residuals

```
list_res = [2.1663149855057022, 12.202467603015915, 13.105388388645999, 3.524702335556132, 5.007101216080126, 2.1989779961023457, 4.6753139694285775, 1.82871868615581, 3.8247209107872857, 2.977690850044372]
```

I want to generate a color plot or density plot with the omega values and the respective absolute values of the residual. The idea is to locate the local minimum points (the points where the residual is closest to zero)

I tried using `plot_comples` from the `spb` library. But apparently you can only plot symbolic functions.

I would like to make a plot similar to the plot below. Where the black dots are the values ​​where `res` is minimum.

[Color plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDK3b.png)

Comment: To create a plot like that, you would want to create a [`meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) of `omega` values and get the residue for those. You can then plot the result in 2D using [`pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html) or in 3D using [`plot_surface`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_surface.html). You should include the `res` function if you want more help.

Comment: Please add the `res` function used for the sympy plotting backend plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how [`spb`](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) creates that kind of visualization:

1. create a grid of omega values in the complex plane.
2. evaluate the function over that complex grid.
3. compute the magnitude of the result, which varies from 0 to (possibly) infinity. The range in values is usually large, so it's not a good idea to plot the magnitude because you'd end up with an image difficult to understand...
4. Instead, we compute the brightness with this formula: `b = m / (m + 1)` where `m` is the magnitude. Note that `b` is zero when `m=0` and `b` tends to one when `m` tends to infinity.
5. plot the brightness.

Here is an example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

func = lambda w: np.sin(w**2)
n = 200j
re_w, im_w = np.mgrid[-3:3:n, -3:3:n]
w = re_w + 1j * im_w
res = func(w)
mag = np.absolute(res)
brightness = mag / (mag + 1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
img = ax.imshow(brightness, cmap="gray", vmin=brightness.min(), vmax=brightness.max())
cbar = fig.colorbar(img, label="brightness")
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to use the method you used, but it gave some errors. Is there any problem in using ```w``` and ```res``` in the formation of one-dimensional lists, as I presented above in the question?

Comment: @ProjetosProgramação To be able to plot it as a grid you will need to generate the grid data. I generally prefer using the `meshgrid` function over `mgrid`, but that's my personal preference. To use that, you'll want to generate a 1D list of the real values and another of the imaginary values and then pass them to `meshgrid`. Also, since this isn't an image, I'd use `pcolormesh` so you can pass the x and y coordinates rather than plotting the indices.

Comment: I tried to do this. I created two lists ```x``` and ```y``` for real omega and imaginary omega. But the third variable ```z```, which would be the absolute value of the residue, would it look like? I already have the explicit 1D list for ```res```. But would q give am function of ```x``` and ```y```?

Comment: Compute the absolute value of the function over your list of omegas. Then, use scipy to interpolate them over a grid (of course, the quality of interpolation depends on many factors, one of which is the number of initial points). Finally, create the plot as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @Davide_sd In the documentation of [`plot_complex`](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/ccomplex.html#spb.ccomplex.complex.plot_complex) it says that it plots the "absolute value of a complex function colored by its argument." The argument is the angle of an imaginary number, `z`, off of the real axis, so wouldn't this mean it's `np.abs(np.angle(z))`? That produces different results than what you show here, so clearly it is wrong, but I'm not sure why your results are what is being plotted by spb.

Comment: @jared note the "absolute value of a complex function", not the "absolute value of the argument". The `plot_complex` [function of spb](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/ccomplex.html#spb.ccomplex.complex.plot_complex) offers several coloring strategies, some of which combines the absolute value `np.absolute(z)` with the argument `np.angle(z)`. Usually, the argument is used as the base coloring, then some enhancements are applied, like showing iso-modulus or iso-argument lines. Other coloring strategies only shows some variation of the magnitude, like the answer above