# How to produce a color plot with numerical data in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, numeric, complex-numbers

I have whrite two codes. Both are intended to find the value of a certain complex variable omega.

The first one is symbolic.  I had a symbolic equation in omega that generates the quantity `res` (the residue of a continued fraction), which is also complex, as follows:

```
from sympy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from spb import plot_complex

def alpha(n, rho, l):
    return n**2 + (2*rho + 2)*n + 2*rho + 1

def beta(n, rho, l):
    return -(2*n**2 + (8*rho + 2)*n + 8*rho**2 + 4*rho + l*(l+1) -3)

def gamma(n, rho, l):
    return n**2 + 4*rho*n + 4*rho**2 - 4

def F_omega(n, rho, l):
    cf = 0
    for i in reversed(range(1,n+1)):
        cf = cf + beta(i, rho, l)/alpha(i, rho, l)
        cf = (-gamma(i, rho, l)/alpha(i, rho, l)) / cf
        res = cf +  beta(0, rho_guess, l)/alpha(0, rho_guess, l) 
    return res

omega = symbols("\omega")
n = 100
rho_guess = 2*I*omega
l=3

def findomega(n, rho_guess, l):
    return lambdify(omega, F_omega(n, rho_guess, l))

f = findomega(n, rho_guess, l)

p = plot_complex(f, (omega, -0.8-0.2j, 0.8+1j), grid=False, coloring="k", n=500)
```

This generates the following plot (where the black dots represent the roots):

[Color_plot_simbolic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZNk2.png)

The second one is numerical, and I am having difficulties generating a color plot similar to the one plotted above. The code that generates the values corresponding to the omega values is given by (simplified)

```
r0 = 0.0001
l = 2
a = R
pc = 5

def alpha(n, a, M, l):
    return n*(n+1)*(a -2*M)

def beta(n, a, M, l, omega):
    return n*(6*M*n -2*a*n -2*1j*omega*a**2)

def gamma(n, a, M, l):
    return (6*M -6*M*n*(n-1) -a*l*(l+1) +a*n*(n-1))

def delta(n, a, M, l):
        return (2*M*(n-2)*n -6*M) 

def match_int_ext(n, omega, l):    
    k0, h0, h1r, kr, wr = [1, -0.0047, 0.3730, 0.9459, -0.0120]
    psi, psil = RW(0.3730, 0.9459, 0.0450, 2, omega, 0.14476)  
    
    list_alpha = [1, 2*(a-2*M)]
    list_beta = [-R*(psil/psi + (1j*R*omega)/(-2*M+R)), 6*M -2*a*(1+1j*a*omega)]
    list_gamma = [0,-a*l*(l+1)+6*M]
    list_delta = [0,0]

    for i in range(2, n+1):
        list_alpha.append(alpha(i, a, M, l))
        list_beta.append(beta(i, a, M, l, omega))
        list_gamma.append(gamma(i, a, M, l))
        list_delta.append(delta(i, a, M, l))
        
    def αhat(n, a, M, l): 
        if n<2:
            return list_alpha[n]
        else:
            return alpha(n, a, M, l)

    def γhat(n, a, M, l, omega):
        if n<2:
            return list_gamma[n]
        else:
            return gamma(n, a, M, l) - (βhat(n-1, a, M, l, omega)*delta(n, a, M, l))/γhat(n-1, a, M, l, omega)    

    def βhat(n, a, M, l, omega):
        if n<2:
            return list_beta[n]
        else:
            return beta(n, a, M, l, omega) - (αhat(n-1, a, M, l)*delta(n, a, M, l))/γhat(n-1, a, M, l, omega)      
  
    cf = 0
    for i in reversed(range(1,n+1)):
        cf = cf + βhat(i, a, M, l, omega)/αhat(i, a, M, l)
        cf = (-γhat(i, a, M, l, omega)/αhat(i, a, M, l)) / cf
        res = βhat(0, a, M, l, omega) + αhat(0, a, M, l)*cf
                
    return res
```

Similar to the previous symbolic case, omega is complex. But this time, I pass a list of omega values as follows:

```
N = 100

omega_re = np.linspace(2, 6, N)
omega_im = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, N)
```

in order to find the corresponding values of res (which is also complex). I'm unsure of how I can plot a color plot in this way. Should I perform interpolation? Should I consider the absolute value... separate or combine the real and imaginary parts? How can I create a color plot in this numerical case?

Comment: (1) What do you mean by color? If you mean not grayscale, then what coloring do you want? (2) Can you share a simplified `res` function?

Comment: Yes, it would be a plot, which I initially generated using plot_complex with a grayscale . I updated the question by imposing the calculated values from other notebooks so that the function ```res``` is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure how this question differs from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76601758/12131013), so my solution is essentially the same as @[Davide_sd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2329968/davide-sd)'s [solution to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76602791/12131013).

You can create `omega` by first creating a `meshgrid` of real and imaginary values and then adding the real part with `1j` times the imaginary part (`1j` is python's way of creating an imaginary number). You can then get `res` from evaluating `F_omega`, which I've renamed to `findomega` since that's what you called it for `spb.plot_complex` (though I'm not sure why you did the `lambdify` since `F_omega` is not a function of `omega` nor does it return a function of `omega`).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

def alpha(n, rho, l):
    return n**2 + (2*rho + 2)*n + 2*rho + 1

def beta(n, rho, l):
    return -(2*n**2 + (8*rho + 2)*n + 8*rho**2 + 4*rho + l*(l+1) -3)

def gamma(n, rho, l):
    return n**2 + 4*rho*n + 4*rho**2 - 4

def findomega(n, rho, l):
    cf = 0
    for i in reversed(range(1,n+1)):
        cf = cf + beta(i, rho, l)/alpha(i, rho, l)
        cf = (-gamma(i, rho, l)/alpha(i, rho, l)) / cf
        res = cf +  beta(0, rho_guess, l)/alpha(0, rho_guess, l) 
    return res

N = 100
omega_re = np.linspace(-0.8, 0.8, N)
omega_im = np.linspace(-0.2, 1., N)
Omega_re, Omega_im = np.meshgrid(omega_re, omega_im)
Omega = Omega_re + 1j*Omega_im

rho_guess = 2j*Omega
l = 3

res = findomega(N, rho_guess, l)
mag = np.abs(res)
brightness = mag/(mag + 1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(omega_re, omega_im, brightness, cmap="gray", shading="gouraud")
ax.set_xlabel("Re")
ax.set_ylabel("Im")
ax.set_aspect(1)
fig.show()
```

[image]